# PageBuilder module missing 2.4.6-p1

Tags: magento2.4.6, page-builder

I've got a fresh server with magento 2.4.6-p1 installed by the providor. The whole PageBuilder module is missing from the installation.

Is that posible to leave-out while installing magento? And if so, how to install it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this through the composer

```
composer require magento/module-page-builder
```

you can install your missing modules through composer.

after applying the below commands.

```
sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && sudo php bin/magento c:f && sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated
```

Comment: Thanks. Module found after i logged into and added repo.magento.com